# SSH into Turtlebot?

Tags: turtlebot, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So my workstation and computer are finally connected, and now it tells me to ssh into the laptop from the workstation. When I type in "ssh turtlebot@192.168.1.101" (the ip of the laptop being 192.168.1.101), I am prompted to enter a password. The password is not the normal password of the computer, and when I guess incorrectly three times, it tells me "Permission denied (publickey,password)". what does this mean? how do I find the publickey?

```
**Here is the info of the laptop**
hyness@turtlebot:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:16:d7:9d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0xc000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:db:c9:9c:b3:ba  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::96db:c9ff:fe9c:b3ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:115679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:410389
          TX packets:107116 errors:19 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32919823 (32.9 MB)  TX bytes:16498997 (16.4 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:187731 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:187731 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24223708 (24.2 MB)  TX bytes:24223708 (24.2 MB)

**From Workstation**
ssh turtlebot@192.168.1.101
turtlebot@192.168.1.101's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
turtlebot@192.168.1.101's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
turtlebot@192.168.1.101's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password)'
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40888/ssh-into-turtlebot?/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-08**:
Normal password of which computer? It should be the password of the turtlebot user on the laptop. Did you try that?

**Comment by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on 2012-08-08**:
yes, I tried that multiple times... why does it mention publickey?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-08-08**:
did you copy your workstations public ssh key to the turtlebot laptop? If so, you might have entered a passphrase for that specific key. Try that one.

**Comment by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on 2012-08-10**:
Thanks! I actually figured this out just now, but i appreciate it!

**Comment by [Bharath Javvadhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20403/bharath-javvadhi/) on 2014-10-13**:
Hi, I am completely new to turtlebot and linux, i am facing the same problem too, I am just using one laptop connected to the turtlebot. When i type in turtlebot@10.23.0.37's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
I have tried the root password but it didnt work.
How to find the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way you are using ssh, you are ssh-ing the turtlebot acount on turtlebot. If you entered "turtlebot", the default password for the turtlebot account, it should log you in. So, to log into your account, run this instead:

```
ssh hyness@192.168.1.101
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2